# Extracting Data via flatMap does not call subscribe

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rxbluetooth

I am trying to extract information from observable with `flatMap` but it won't call subscribe after that. When I return `Observable.just(it)` from `flatMap` subscribe is called as expected but then I am not able to get the information.

```
conn.setupNotification(UUID_GATT_DFU_DEVICE_FIRMWARE_UPDATE_STATUS, NotificationSetupMode.COMPAT)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .doOnNext{
                    Timber.d("this is called")
                }
                .flatMap {
                    Timber.d("this is called")
                    //Observable.just(it) with this subscribe is called
                    it
                }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                    { status ->
                        Timber.d("NOTIFY RESPONSE STATUS: @@@ $status")
                    },
                    {
                        Timber.d(it)
                    },
                    {
                        Timber.d("ON COMPLETE notify observer")
                    }
                ).also {
                    notificationDisposable.add(it)
                }
```

what am I doing wrong? I need to extract the observable but how when flatMap doesn't work as expected? I also tried another subscribe in onNext method but it also didn't work.

Comment: What information are you trying to get? What is the input to that `flatMap`? Why do you use `flatMap`?

Comment: There is Observable<ByteArray> and i need that ByteArray. Iam using flatMap to get rid of Observable.

Comment: It should be `flatMap { it }` or `concatMap { it }`.

Comment: look at my code. I have flatMap{ it }

Comment: Yes I saw that. What is the problem then? Maybe that inner `Observable` has no data to work with after the flattening.

Comment: it has for sure because before this notification iam writing data to another charactics and this just should gave me how it end up. I have tried concatMap but i got same result. It just wont continue to next method `.doOnNext{
                    Timber.d("this is called")
                }.concatMap {
                    it
                }.doOnNext{
                    Timber.d("aaaaaaaaa")
                }` "aaaaa" is never called

Comment: Try `concatMap { it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) }`.

Comment: same result. nothing.

Comment: I think you simply don't get data. You check if `it` actually does produce items: `it.doOnNext { System.out.println("Data!") }`.